# Easily pass super class into sub class

Tags: python

If I am writing a code as

```
class Robot(object):

    def __init__(self, room, position):

        self.position=position
        self.room=room

        self.direction=random.randrange(0,360)

class DuckRobot(Robot):

    def move(self,position2)

        self.position=self.position + position2
        return self.position
```

Now if I have already created a `Robot` as `r=Robot('My',5)` and want `DuckRobot` to inherit all the arguments how do I do that? simply `duck=DuckRobot(r)` does not work. Also will the value of self.position in r change if change the value from `DuckRobot`.(I am planning to have multiple robots so need the base class)

Comment: `duck = DuckRobot("My", 5)`. You don't need `r`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think the OP means they will have multiple types of robots to justify the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious way to do it is to just grab the attributes you need from the existing object when creating the new object:

```
duck = DuckRobot(r.room, r.position)
```

But this involves a lot of "repeating yourself" and grows to be cumbersome as the number of arguments increases. There are better ways, such as:

1. Write `__init__()` to also accept another instance of `Robot`, and extract the values needed for the new object from that instance.
2. Write a class method called e.g. `from_robot()` that accepts another instance, and extracts the necessary values from that.
3. Write a method that returns the salient attributes for constructing a new instance, and pass those when constructing.

Of these three methods, changing `__init__()` is pretty much the worst choice, because you need to accept two different sets of values. That means you have to make all arguments optional and add code to make sure a valid combination was passed. So we'll skip that. (You could use `functools.singledispatch()` to write these variants, but that feature was only added in Python 3.4., and it seems like overkill anyway.)

Here's the class method... method:

```
class Robot(object):

    def __init__(self, room, position):
        self.position=position
        self.room=room
        self.direction=random.randrange(0,360)

    @classmethod
    def from_robot(cls, robot):
        return cls(robot.room, robot.position)
```

Now you can construct a `DuckRobot` from an existing `Robot` instance `r` with:

```
duck = DuckRobot.from_robot(r)
```

Finally, here's the "return the salient attributes" method. We'll use a property here so you don't have to call it:

```
class Robot(object):

    def __init__(self, room, position):
        self.position=position
        self.room=room
        self.direction=random.randrange(0,360)

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return self.room, self.position
```

Then you can create a new `DuckRobot` from `r` like so:

```
duck = DuckRobot(*r.attributes)
```

I personally prefer the class method option (alternate constructors are pretty much the #1 use case for class methods) and most Python programmers would have the same preference. If you already want something like the `attributes` property for another purpose, though, you might as well reuse it.

Comment: I, too, prefer the class method. The `attributes` property feels like it is exposing too many details unnecessarily.

Comment: Surely the classmethod should take `cls` as a parameter and use it to instantiate the actual class, not Robot?

Comment: Yep, you're right, just fixed that along with a few other edits.